# Django REST Framework: Using the Accept-Language header to set an instance's "locale"

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, request, django-3.0

So, I have a model with the following attribute:

```
locale = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=get_locale_choices(), default='en-gb')
```

The associated serializer for this model is currently:

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = '__all__'
```

I then call a create endpoint:

```
serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)

serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

self.perform_create(serializer)
```

I was wondering, how best to modify the above to allow the locale attribute of MyModel to be updated by the Accept-Language header `en-GB,en;q=0.5`.

I get my locale choices from django.conf.locale.LANG_INFO:

```
from django.conf.locale import LANG_INFO

def get_locale_choices():
    return [(k, v['name']) for k, v in LANG_INFO.items() if 'name' in v]
```

I guess I need to pass in the request.headers as some sort of extra context...? But I'm thinking, what if the Accept-Language is not set, etc? I know it is here:

```
request.headers['Accept-Language']
```

So, I guess `request.headers.get('Accept-Language', 'en-gb')` would be acceptable ...

But then, what would be the best way to then set the attribute in the serialzier as this?

N.B. I also believe `get_serializer_context()` can return the request object?

I also feel this could be robust enough:

```
data = request.POST.copy()

serializer = self.get_serializer(data=data.update({'locale': request.headers.get('Accept-Language', 'en')}))
```

But is this, "good practise"?

Opinions are warmly welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without *"much considering the `locale`"* try this method to save any data from request.

1. First you need to set the **`locale`** field to **`read_only`**

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = ('locale',)
```

2. override the **`perform_create(...)`** method of the ModelViewset or similar viewclass

```
class MyModelViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    # other code
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(locale=self.request.headers.get('Accept-Language', 'en-gb'))
```